# Python Tkinter Tic Tac Toe AI

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe in tkinter however I am running into some problems with the AI system. What I'm trying to do is that if the middle spot isn't taken it will chose it and if it isn't it will pick a random number and map out all the routes it can take to win and all the routes the player will use and for it to block them however I am running into this problem. My code:

```
def click1():
    if isTaken1 == False:
        Button1.config(text = "O")
        pTurn1 = True

Button1 = Button(root, command = click1)
Button1.config(width = "5", height = "3")
Button1.place(x = 100, y = 30)
#I have nine of these however I can't show them all as it will make this post very long
```

I am trying to add it when the player takes a turn (The pTurn variable) it will make the AI act however, I have no idea where to put the AI code.

I am trying to do something like:

```
If isTaken5 == False: #Checking if the middle spot is taken
    Button5.config(text = "X") #Player is O and AI is X
else:
    AIChoice = random.randint(1,8)
    if AIChoice == 1:
        Button1.config(text = "X")
```

So you get the basic idea for it, but I have no idea where to put the cod as if statements put after where you change it don't work.

Comment: You would need some kind of game loop. Something like "while(gameNotOver)". Put your logic/AI inside the loop.

Comment: @TheEyesHaveIt: tkinter apps already run in a loop, so another loop isn't necessary. In a turn-based game, they only need to apply the logic when it is the computers turn (ie: either at the start, or after each turn by the player)

Comment: @BryanOakley Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

In a turn-based game, you can call the AI function immediately after the user takes their turn. For example, let's start with a function for the computer's turn. This is where your ai exists:

```
def computer_turn():
    <your logic to pick an empty square>
```

Ideally you'll also want to check for the case where the computer picked the last place, but I've left that out now to keep the example simple.

Next, we have a function for the player's turn. In this example, it takes a row and column that was clicked on. This will select the button that was clicked, check to see if the game is over, and call `computer_turn` if the game isn't over yet.

It would look something like this:

```
def player_turn(row, column):        
    <your logic to select the given row and column>
    
    if not is_game_over():
        computer_turn()
```

This isn't the only way to handle the game logic. You could create a small state machine, for example. However, for a game as simple as tic-tac-toe, this turn-based system is good enough.